# What's the simplest way to set all values in a column to null in CQL?

Tags: cassandra

If it helps at all, I want to set them all to NULL, like in `update foo set barcol = null`. This particular command results in a complaint about a missing primary key constraint. In the case of a select statement, a similar error can be worked around by adding the clause `allow filtering`. Is there any similar workaround in this case? If not, what would be the simplest way to achieve this?

UPDATE: Is there anything better than this not-very-nice solution that I have?

```
cqlsh -e 'select id from foo' | head -n -3 | tail -n +4 | \
  xargs -I{} cqlsh -e "update foo set barcol = null where id = '{}'"
```

Comment: Something like what you have might be reasonable. Consider that Cassandra is built for horizontal scalability. How would you design a database to do this across a large cluster - say, 1000 nodes? 10,000? A single update for something like that could run for days, so a user would perhaps use something like Spark in that case.

Comment: How many rows are you talking about in your case? If it's small, perhaps keeping a list of the row keys in a "special" row would work. That is, add a column to the special row every time you add a target row. When you want to null, spin through the columns on the special row, and null the column on each target row.

Comment: Just curious, but what is your goal with this?  Are you hoping to ignore or invalidate the data?  It wouldn't be too expensive to do it for each individual key, especially if you do a bunch asynchronously, writes in cassandra are cheap.  I think Don Branson is asking the right questions, has good suggestions.

Comment: Did you try altering the table to first drop the column, and then altering it again to add it back?  I'm not sure if that would be efficient, but when you add a new column to an existing table, it will have a value null in all the existing rows.

Comment: Alter table drop, alter table add works pretty well for me, and faster than the above technique.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen discussions about problems in C* if you just drop the column and recreate it to ensure the contents is null. I think that renaming the column, add new column and then delete the renamed column is the safest way to do this.

So

`ALTER TABLE RENAME col TO col_deleted`

`ADD COLUMN col <type>`

`ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN col_deleted`

Is in my mind the best way to ensure only null values.